# Chrome fullscreen windows

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fullscreen

I have two Google Chrome windows, Window A, and Window B. I have full-screened Window B with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. But, Window A also becomes fullscreen. When I un-fullscreen Window A with  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, Window B becomes un-full-screened.

Is there any way to have one Chrome window fullscreen and the other one normal?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works for you to make the window full screen. I am using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to make the window full screen and revert to normal.

If you are not using any extension like magnet, The possible issue might be that when you switch your window might not have been cycled, for which you will need to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> followed by  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same starting position as you (two single Google Chrome windows). When I navigate one of the two windows and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the selected window becomes full screen, and the other window remains in normal mode, an becomes not also fullscreen as described in your problem...

When I click your key combination as described in your question above (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), nothing happens...

So you have written this key combination to a *keyboard customizer* like [Karabiner-Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)? If yes, remove this rule and try it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.